# Firedac / Anydac query issue when using updatesql components

Tags: delphi, ms-access, firedac, anydac

The following question is related to **firedac** using `adquery`, `updatesql` with access database:

First the scenario:

In one of scenario my `updatesql` gives an error i-e data in the table was not updated, however my dataset after showing error moves to next record. But now data is not in sync with table grid, which is based on this dataset*(adquery)* show updated version which was not successfully applied.
Yet the table still has the old version of the given record.

---

And my question:

- If an error occurs during modification how to know that `modifysql`
  was not run successfully and trap that error to refresh the dataset
  as per data in table?

Comment: How do you fire the update mechanism? By executing the 'applyupdates' method?  This method returns a value of how many errors have occurred.  Also you can use the 'onreconcile' event to deal with errors.

Comment: No it is not cached update query

Comment: I am using OnUpdateRecord event by executing another query in this event. Can I capture the error occured in that other query. Also how to use onreconcile event.

Comment: When using OnUpdateRecord there is an 'onupdateerror' event.  For the reconcile event, the best I can do is refer you to the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.OnReconcileError